# How to read numerical data from the comment of a .txt file into numpy

Tags: python, numpy, text, import, scipy

Suppose I have some .txt files as the output of measurements of experiments:

```
Date: 160818
double polished Si 300 microns
Power before sample: 62.7uW
Power after sample: 33.0uW
position    y1  y2  power
1.00E-01    1.93E+07    1.17E+06    2.32E-05
2.00E-01    1.92E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
3.00E-01    1.93E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
4.00E-01    1.94E+07    1.16E+06    2.30E-05
5.00E-01    1.94E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
6.00E-01    1.93E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
7.00E-01    1.94E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
8.00E-01    1.94E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
9.00E-01    1.93E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
1.00E+00    1.93E+07    1.16E+06    2.32E-05
```

I know how to ignore the comments at the top and just import the data using `np.loadtxt(... ,skiprows=5)`. But let's say I want to import the values of the power before/afer sample, which are 62.7 and 33.0, how do I do it?

thanks

Comment: Use regular python file reading and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Regular Expression (REGEX):

```
import re
```

Save each line of text into a list:

```
with open ("power.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
```

Iterate through the list to find the matching "number strings":

```
match = list()
for i in range(len(data)):

    match1 = re.search('[0-9]+[.][0-9]+', data[i]) # REGEX

    # Matching numbers are appended
    if match1:
        match.append(match1[0])
```

You can then easily iterate through the new list to print out the numbers:

```
for i in range(len(match)):
    print(match[i])
```

You can see that this method allows you to obtain the numbers in the table too.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the files like normal.
Just skip the first 2 rows and do string manipulation on rows 3 and 4

something like

```
before = rows[0] //first row
before = before[21:-2]
```

if I'm counting correctly will give you the numbers. If you want them as numbers instead of string you can just

```
before = float(before)
```

In other words, just use string manipulation once you've imported the row.

Answer (score 1):

This just to make Mr Steele's answer slightly more explicit.

```
with open('physicist.txt') as f:
    f.readline()
    f.readline()
    print(float(f.readline()[21:-3].strip()))
    print(float(f.readline()[20:-3].strip()))
```

Output:

```
62.7
33.0
```